# universal connection for SU(3)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics

In 1961, Narasimhan and Ramanan (Am J Math 83 563) showed that one could represent an arbitrary SU(3) connection as $ i t^c_{a b} A^c_\mu(x) = e^*_a \cdot e_{b, \mu}(x) $ in which the $ t^a $'s are the $ 3 \times 3 $ hermitian generators of SU(3), $ x $ is a spacetime point in $ \mathbb{R}^4 $, and the three complex, orthonormal vectors $ e_b(x) $ are vectors that have no more than 81 complex components.

What is the minimum number of components that the three vectors $ e_b(x) $ must have?

Comment: Could you be more precise?  Are you asking for a way to find the minimum number that works for a *given* connection in dimension 4 or are you asking for the minimum number that works for *all* connections in dimension 4?  Also, are you asking for the minimum number that works locally or the minimum number that works globally?

Comment: I am asking for the minimum number that works globally for all connections in dimension 4.